# Algebraic graph theory identities?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, optimization

### My Background

I am an outsider to graph theory and wanted to ask some questions about an approach I recently constructed.

### Example Network

A network with $5$ nodes and the distance between is shown below:

[image: Graph]

Using bra-ket notation I figured a nice way to express this problem which can be generalized to any network problem. We define the following projection operators with $x^D$ as a distance between the two nodes:

$$ \hat 1 = x |1 \rangle \langle 2 | + x |1 \rangle \langle 3 | + x^2 |1 \rangle \langle 4 | $$

$$ \hat 2 = x |2 \rangle \langle 1| + x^2 | 2 \rangle \langle 5 |$$

$$ \hat 3 = x |3\rangle \langle 1| + x |3\rangle \langle 4| $$

$$ \hat 4 = x^2 |4 \rangle \langle 1| + x |4 \rangle \langle 5| + x |4 \rangle \langle 3|$$

$$ \hat 5 = x^2 |5 \rangle \langle 2|+ x |5 \rangle \langle 4|$$

Notice, if someone starts at $1$ and ends at $5$. The distance of a possible path $ 1 \to 3 \to 4 \to 5$ is given by the power of $x$:

$$ \langle 1 | \hat 1 \hat 3 \hat 4 | 5 \rangle = x^3 $$

Hence the distance of this path is $3$ m.

Let $s$ be the number nodes it transverses from $1 \to 5$:

$$ \langle 1 | (\hat 1 + \hat 2 + \hat 3 + \hat 4 + \hat 5)^s | 5 \rangle = \sum_i  x^{D_i}$$

### Questions

Does this approach to graph theory already exist? Where can I learn more about this approach from? I also noticed some identities:

$$ \sum \hat r = \sum \hat r^T$$

Further one can set $x=1$ or differentiate and then set $x=1$ to get more identities. What are some other graph theory identities one can extract? Is there a method to minimize $D$?

Comment: You say you found a nice way to express this problem, but you have not told us what problem you are talking about.

Comment: Your operators number-hat are not projections.

Comment: In any case, the sum of the hats of all vertices is the adjacency matrix of the graph. Google for that.

Comment: This is basically the transfer-matrix method.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I was trying to see is there was some method to minimize the distance $D$ algebraically?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown any book recommendations for algebric graph theory for a physics background person?

Comment: @AnantSaxena, then explain that in the question!